# WSO2 apim exporting/importing multiple apis from APIM publisher from develop environment to QA / production environment

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

How to do a WSO2 apim exporting/importing of multiple apis from APIM publisher from develop environment to QA / production environment . Say I have a 15 Apis defined in APIM publisher with params , need these to be exported to another environment where another wso2 APIM is hosted in that environment with a different db in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

API Import-Export tool can only be used to migrate APIs in between different environments of the same APIM version. This is not supported for Migrating APIs across different APIM versions. Therefore, It is really suit for your requirement.

But, we can export multiple APIs at once using the WSO2 API Manager import/export tool. Using the command in the following documentation[1] you can export all APIs of a particular tenant.

But importing multiple APIs is not supported at all.

Further, exporting or importing number of APIs as per our choice(like two, three APIs) is also not possible right now.

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-controller/migrating-apis-to-different-environments/#export-all-the-apis-of-a-tenant-at-once

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CLI tool for [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Migrating+the+APIs+and+Applications+to+a+Different+Environment). From that wso2 apim allows you to import/export both APIs and Applications among multiple environments on the same version.